# How to upload lower version IPA in Apple Test Flight?

Tags: ios, itunes, testflight, ipa, itunes-store

I have `v1.1.1` and `v1.1.3` in TestFlight server. Is it possible to completely remove `1.1.3` and then upload `v1.1.2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even need to remove 1.1.3, you can just upload a new build for 1.1.2, as long as the build number is different to any existing builds for 1.1.2

Comment: Previously we tried but failed with reply "Build needs to be greater" this type of messages. Is it allowed from later versions?

Comment: I just tried; I have an app with 1.0 currently in TestFlight and I was able to upload a build of version 0.9; it appeared in the TetFlight list even though I don't have a version 0.9 of the app under the "iOS app" list on the left of iTunes connect